# Can't see my picture that I use in my webSite

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I use a template for my website and I fill its cells with an Image control and set that with the URl of picture, but when I upload my website I can't see that Picture.

I Created a new folder for all Images and use Master page for this website.

LINK : http://www.aalaa.ir/az/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please include your ASP.NET code that shows the ImageUrl path. This can happen if the path  to the image is incorrect. Try formatting your paths using "~". Like this:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/image/header.jpg" />
```

Instead of:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="image/header.jpg" />
```

Comment: In addition to the ImageUrl modification to include "~", make sure that you have images in the folder. The only image there now is "Logo 04.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

MasterPages often require special treatment of URLs and paths. This is called URL rebasing. You begin the path with the tilde character (~) to refer to the website's root.

Viewing the source of your web page, here is one of the image tags that ASP.Net has provided:

```
src="Image/Logo%2004.jpg"
```

So, try adding at the beginning "~/" like this:

```
src="~/Image/Logo%2004.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no images in your images folder...

http://www.aalaa.ir/az/image/